# 301 redirect .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to request the following entire site 301 redirect:

word.something.blah.domain.com --> http://www.word.com

I don't know how to write the 301 redirect rule.

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are using the same directory to serve files on both domains. In which case, a `Redirect` clause won't work (infinite redirect loop).

With `mod_rewrite`, you can check the value of the current `HTTP_HOST` and take a decision based on that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.something\.blah\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: This works really great Andrew. Thanks! Everything redirects now except .txt files from the previous site such as robots.txt.

Answer (score 0):

put this into root directory of the subdomain:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.word.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping everything else the same - that is, the file names - but simply changing the domain, this code is all you need to put on the OLD DOMAIN htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```