# Change displayed URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How could I rewrite my URL using HTACCESS?

When a visitor visits index.php, I want the URL to be rewritten to something else, although the visitor will remain on the index.php page.

This is what I've tried (I did research this before asking but couldn't solve it myself):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ testingit.php
```

Basically, I just wanted to change index.php to 'testingit.php', just to see if it would work.

Comment: So when someone visits `index.php` you actually want to serve up the `testinggit.php` page or do you want to redirect them to that page? Can you be a bit more clear of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No, I want him to see 'testingit.php' while he's on index.php

Comment: Then you need to redirect. Rewrite means, I visit `domain.com/a/` but the server actually looks and gets something else `domain.com/b/` but the url still says `domain.com/a/`.

Comment: Oh, is there any guide out there which explains what the functions do (cause i've been looking but couldn't get any answers at all).

Comment: Possibly ansered by [301 redirect .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217209/301-redirect-htaccess)

Comment: Ah I see, this is not what I ment. What I actually ment was that whenever the visitor visits index.php, the url has to be rewritten to something else (but that still has to mean that the visitor is on the index.php page).

Comment: So you mean what I said in the first comment. The visitor goes to `index.php` and their URL still says `index.php` but the webpage content actually comes from `testinggit.php`.

Comment: No no no :P The visitor visits the page (index.php), index.php has been loaded but the visitor's url has been changed to 'testingit.php'. Nothing changes but the url (in fact, it just replaces it with something I want, in this case 'testingit.php')

Comment: You can't use htaccess to just change the URL. htaccess will either server a different page or redirect to a different page. What you want is a redirect. Or you could change the visible URL with Javascript (bad idea). You are misunderstanding what Rewrite means in this context. Rewrite means the server takes a url like `domain.com/page/type/` but on the server is actually looks for `domain.com/?page=type` or however you configure it. It can't change the URL in the browser other than redirecting them user to a different page.

Comment: Then how do people execute this idea for SEO? So for example, http://testdomain.com/articles/3600/see-this-is-what-you-get instead of http://testdomain.com?articleid=3600

Comment: The sever redirected you to another page. It didn't magically change the URL in your browser. The server received your request to that page, saw in the htaccess that with that request it should send you somewhere else and did so.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how that is done then? Cause i'm pretty confused right now :(

Comment: I would argue 301 is not great for SEO either. The better solution is to setup that page to serve that content as with 301s SEO juice is "lost" somewhat. It's not always possible, in this case, they are different domains. See the answer below. You can change `http://www.yoursite.com/testingit.php` to `http://google.com`. When a user hits your index file it will send them to google.

Comment: Well, 'testingit.php' was just an example, eventually I would be changing 'testingit.php' to /home. So my URL would be looking like this: http://mydomain.or/home (instead of http://mydomain.or/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `testwebsite/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testwebsite/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ home [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write that, but unfortanetly it doesn't work for me.. I'm not sure why since I don't see any mistakes made

Comment: My apologies, I get the error 404 message. Didn't visit the link properly. Besides, the htacces file is located inside the directory 'testwebsite' and is sitting next to index.php

Comment: uhm, i'm not receiving any errors while putting this on top of the htacces file 'sa;lksadweqiokkdlss;ladsad,;lx;l,xz;l,;,lxc;,;l,d;lsadl;sad;,lwdsadsadsasda'. I'm using WAMP and my rewrite_module is activated, so I guess this isn't the problem.

Comment: It has to be actived, it also give's me a notification that it is activated.

Comment: It did, now I have another question (asking alot, i'm sorry). Is it possible to disable the whole url 'localhost/testwebsite/index.php' and whenever the visitor DO visits that specefic url he'll be redirected to 'localhost/testwebsite/home'?

Answer (score 1):

So here's how you do it:

```
redirect *** /index.php http://www.yoursite.com/testingit.php
```

You need to replace *** with one of the following:

301-For a permanent redirect meaning browsers update bookmarks etc.

**or**

302-For a temporary redirect

Here's a link to a guide I found:

https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Hope this helps :)

To make pretty URL's:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^home/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Tried it out, with the following line 'Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.yoursite.com/testingit.php' but still doesn't seem to react

Comment: Can you post your entire .htaccess file as well. And is mod_rewrite enabled? Not just On, but I believe it has to be enabled in Apache.

Comment: Nothing much above that code, 'RewriteEngine on' is the only line above it, and yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: Please post you htaccess file

Comment: @AdminAlex RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.yoursite.com/testingit.php

Comment: is index.php in a folder? and you need to replace yoursite.com with your site name

Comment: It is indeed in a folder, named testwebsite

Comment: redirect 301 testwebsite/index.php http://www.yoursite.com/testwebsite/testingit.php

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen

Comment: @AdminAlex instead of 'localhost/testingwebsite/index.php' -> 'localhost/testingwebsite/home'

Comment: you want the address www.example.com/testingwebsite/index.php to go to www.example.com/testingwebsite/home/testing.php

Comment: @AdminAlex No, I just want the url to change but the location to be the same. So whenever the visitor visits my website he won't see index.php but instead /home

Comment: Try the above bottom of the original answer "make pretty URLs"