# display different url and load different page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to display another url in browser and load a different page's content.

for example , when user visits

```
http://starattestation.com/saudi.aspx  //URL I WANT TO BE DISPLAYED IN BROWSER.
```

then content of below url should be displayed.

```
http://starattestation.com/saudi-embassy-attestation-services/
```

I checked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650646/change-displayed-url-using-htaccess) , but i could not achieve it.

**EDIT :** 
Here is my code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?saudi\.aspx$ /saudi-embassy-attestation-services/ [END]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: we cannot help without giving more details. What did you try? Please post the current code you are using and explain in detail what is wrong, what does not work, what actually happens.

Comment: This looks like a Wordpress website and internal rewrite rules don't work with WP framework. You should use rewrite API of WP for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unclear why all the other examples did not enable you to achieve your goal we can only give a very general answer here which basically only repeats what you already read in other answers:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?saudi\.aspx$ /saudi-embassy-attestation-services/ [END]
```

For this to work some preconditions must be fulfilled:

- the interpretation of dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") needs to be enabled
- the rewriting module must be loaded into the http server

In case you receive a http status 500 using above rule chances are that you operate a very old and outdated version of the apache http server. In that case try changing the `[END]` flag to `[L]`.

In general one should always prefer to place such rules into the actual http server's host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, add complexity, are hard to debug and they really slow down the http server's operation. They are only provided as a last means for situations where you do *not* have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap web service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rewriting rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thanks for your help, I placed your rule into my htaccess file but I can not load http://starattestation.com/saudi.aspx page . it goes to 404 page. can you please help ?

Comment: So what does `http://starattestation.com/saudi-embassy-attestation-services/` result in if requested directly?